# Regular Expression: Match everything except one specific character

Tags: regex, xml, pcre

I try to make a specific expression but I am not able to solve my actual problem. Maybe some of you can...

I have the string:

```
<!ENTITY a0 "dosdosdosdosdosdosdosdosdosdosdosdosdosdos"
```

and now I want to match everything (at least 10 characters) inbetween the quotation marks, except a quotation mark.

I started with:

```
"(.{10,}?)"
```

at the first sight, this matches very well, but this also matches the following string which is wrong for me.

```
<!ENTITY a0 "dosd" 
<!ENTITY a0 "osdos"
```

The match starts with the first quotation mark of the first line and ends with the last quotation marks of the last line.

I understand why this happens, but I am not able to build a regular expression which matches every character 10 times except a quotation mark. The dot is just too generic.

edit: new problem

new string:

```
<data>&a0;&a0;asddd&a0;&a0;&a0; 234324&a0;&a0;&a0;&a0;&a0;&a0;</data>
```

now i tried to match specific expressions inbetween those two XML-tags till the first "<" occurs. Inbetween these tags I need the appeareance of at least 10 "&a0" which results in

```
&[a-zA-Z0-9]+;
```

The problem is, that different other character strings (except < ) also may occur inbetween those tags. Is this possible to solve?

I tried with:

```
<[a-zA-Z0-9]+>([^<]{10,}?)<\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+>
```

But can now it matches everything and not the wanted &[a-zA-Z0-9]+;

Thanks, guys!

Comment: `"([^"]{10,}?)"` just do the negative character group `[^"]`  everything except `"`
or restrict it even further if you are sure only characters appear between the dots: something like `[a-z]{10,}` or `[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,}` could be useful

Comment: In the second example with two lines your expression matches now everythin inbetween the 2nd and 3rd quotation mark. The problem is that I don't know which character set is allowed inbetween these quotation marks in XML documents.

Comment: Use `"([^"\r\n]{10,}?)"`, grab Group 1 value. Probably, `"(\w{10,}?)"` will be better.

Comment: just exclude the newline as well then

Comment: This works for me! Thanks guys!

Comment: edited with a new problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
"([^"\r\n]{10,})"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3URCVW/1).

The `[^"\r\n]{10,}` pattern matches 10 or more occurrences of any char but `"`, CR and LF.

Note you may use a greedy limiting (range/interval) quantifier here.

To restrict a generic pattern, a good idea is to check your requirements. If you actually plan to match letters, digits and `_`, you may replace the `[^"\r\n]` negated character class with a `\w` shorthand character class.

Comment: added a new problem!

Comment: @Mischu That should be  posted as a separate question.

Comment: You can only post once every 90 minutes. You can see it in 30 minutes :P Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mischu Wait, maybe `<[a-zA-Z0-9]+>(?:[^<]*?&[a-zA-Z0-9]+;){10,}[^<]*<\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+>` is all you need. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/3URCVW/3)